# Google Play have Rejected Android Auto App for Full screen correct DHU model

Tags: java, android, kotlin, google-play, android-auto

I have published Alpha Testing Application APK build of Android Auto Support App. 
but Google Play have rejected the app of following reason:

**Full screen correct DHU model**

**Your app functions on head unit models which are not authorized to display the app. Make sure your app functions only on the head unit models relevant to your app.**

I have tested app on DHU, its working fine and I have followed Android Auto [**Auto app quality**](https://developer.android.com/docs/quality-guidelines/auto-app-quality)

My question is, Which changes required in mine Auto app will be Android support for Android Auto?

*Thanks in advance!!*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about app stores are off-topic. See meta

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems to tell you exactly what the problem is:

"Your app functions on head unit models which are not authorized to display the app". In other words, as well as working on DHU head units, your app works on other head units

"Make sure your app functions only on the head unit models relevant to your app."
In other words, it sounds like your app should check to see what head unit it is running on. If it is not the right one (DHU), it should refuse to run. It should probably also have some targeting in the manifest to make sure it only gets delivered to correct head units.

I'm not sure how the error message could be much clearer.

Comment: Thank you, I will check @Nick Fortescue